# preg_replace() quotes within quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a PHP `serialize()`'d string coming from an external source:

`s:4:"0.00";s:4:"type";s:5:"price";s:3:"$20";s:12:"Foo "Bar" Baz";s:1:"y";`

I need to replace `"Bar"` with `&quot;Bar&quot;` in order to successfully `unserialize()`.

How can I use `preg_replace()` to accomplish this?

I tried `(?<!s:\d{1,4}:)("[0-9a-zA-Z ]+")`, but PHP throws look-behind errors: *lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 14*

*Update: This is a dummy string that I made up. I incorrectly counted the characters... it's safe to assume the count is correct... the string should actually be:*

`s:4:"0.00";s:4:"type";s:5:"price";s:3:"$20";s:13:"Foo "Bar" Baz";s:1:"y";`

Comment: Why does the external source send invalid data?

Comment: Why this complicated RegEx ? You can just use something like `preg_replace('/\"Bar\"/', '&quot;Bar&quot;', $str);` or just `str_replace('\"Bar\"', '&quot;Bar&quot;', $str);`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV That won't work if the string itself is `"Bar"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string can be deserialized do so and then use `htmlspecialchars` to replace the quotes (and also `<` and `>`) with HTML entities. If you want to replace *only* quotes use `str_replace`.

---

The problem in your code is **not** the fact that there are quotes! Actually, escaping the quotes will not solve your problem.

Let's look at the representation of the serialized string you have: `s:12:"Foo "Bar" Baz";`
This means you have a **s**tring containing `12` characters - quotes do not need to be escape in there at all.

Now what's the problem with the serialized data you have?

```
s:12:"Foo "Bar" Baz";
      1234567890123
```

As you can see, you have 13 characters while the parser expects only 12 characters. That's the reason why you cannot unserialize it! This however means that you need to change the `12` to `13` to fix it.

What does this actually mean? **It is impossible to fix your data using a regular expression!** What you actually need to do is fix the source which sends you invalid data!

Comment: I really appreciate your response, but that was a stupid translation error on my behalf. The string coming from the external source does not actually contain `"Foo "Bar" Baz"`-- I incorrectly counted the characters when I wrote the question. Sigh, it was 3am. Apologies. It's safe to assume the count is correct.

Comment: In this case there is absolutely no reason to mess with the serialized data at all - work with the PHP array you get *after* unserializing it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/(s:\d+:\")(.*?)(\";)/i', function($matches){
  return $matches[1] . htmlspecialchars($matches[2], ENT_QUOTES) . $matches[3];
}, $string);
```

(this will fail if you have semicolon following quotes in your string, like `Foo "Bar"; Foo`)

---

@ThiefMaster is right. An attempt to fully correct the string:

```
$keys = 0;
$string = preg_replace_callback('/s:(\d+):\"(.*?)\";/i',
  function($matches) use(&$keys){
    return sprintf('i:%d;s:%d:"%s";', ++$keys, strlen($matches[2]), $matches[2]);
  }, $string);

$string = sprintf('a:%d:{%s}', $keys, $string);
$result = unserialize($string);
```

I've wrapped this in an array, because if you unserialize what you have there, you only get the value of the first element...

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace('|( "[0-9A-Z]+" )|ei', " stripslashes(htmlentities('$1')) ", $str)
```

Comment: -1 for using the `e` modifier. `eval` is bad. always. Use `preg_replace_callback` instead if you need to run code for each replacement.